# RecyclerView Adapter - Where can you access item view after Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 onBindViewHolder
```

Is a nice method but there is one problem - The View has not necessarily been measured yet. So where can I adjust things like amount of content in TextView's etc if I cannot get the actual measurements on the View? I want to change dynamically change the length of Strings rendered in the Item view if the ItemView is a certain width in comparison to the string length. I have measured the CharSet length etc. No problem, but how do I know if it is too long if I cannot measure the width of the View? with the items played out.  The String can also be between two items etc. So I need to at least know where I can access this kind of information. Thanks.

Comment: probably you should use something like this : https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText Because, on my opinion, this should be done by `EditText` not in `onBindViewHolder`. According to documentation `onBindViewHolder` - "Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener to listen for changes in the view tree and get the view's width and height after it has finished measurement.

```
final ViewTreeObserver obs = mTextView.getViewTreeObserver();
obs.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw () {
        int height = mTextView.getHeight();
        int width = mTextView.getWidth();

        // Return true to proceed with the current drawing pass, or false to cancel.
        return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Any suggestions about how to reduce number of times it needs to get called?  Is it just going to be same inside recycler view every time?  Also is this measure after its layed out for the content inside? Like the text string is considered in giving the view its dimensions? Only concern is it gets called many many time ...

Comment: @gitsensible pretty sure it is after laying out the content. Since what you are trying to do now is optimizing, it is difficult to provide an answer without knowing what your adapter/layout is like. If your `ViewHolder` are mostly the same, you might be able to cache the width/height in your adapter after the first time your listener is called. I would suggest getting your app to work first then benchmark it before deciding if you need to optimize it.

Comment: Ok here is the measure of the TextView: TV.width=306 TV.measuredWidth =306  contentItem.MeasuredWidth=384 contentItem.width =384  TheSpannable.measuredWidth =159

Comment: the string is a bit longer and measures a bit more than: TV.width=312 TV.measuredWIdth =312 ItemView.MeasuredWidth=384 ItemView.Width=384 Spannable.measuredw=169   Yet the String is too long for the item?  Seems like 169 should fit.  I guess it's a grid layout which might account for that.  But the TV is already 312 so seems plenty to handle the Scannable. The String is being cut off at 169 measure or an additional few characters maybe 5 or six.

Comment: am using this to calculate the measure of the Scannable assigned to the TV:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245809/calculate-spannablestring-witdh/10613819#10613819  - perhaps it really takes up more space?