# Allign one string on the left and second one on the right side of textView

Tags: java, android, string, textview

So I'm facing little problem with proper allign strings in my TextView. I have 2 strings (left and right) and TextView that has `match_parent` width. The point is that every solution I find doesn't worked (or doesn't work as I want).

So some code:

```
        String LeftText = "Left";
        String RightText = "Right";
        SpannableString finalString = new SpannableString(LeftText+ " " + RightText);
        finalString.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), LeftText.length() , LeftText.length() +RightText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(finalString);
```

I find similar code that works here: [solution that works partly](https://String%20LeftText%20=%20tipPercentage1;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20String%20RightText%20=%20tipCurrency1%20+%20%22%20%22%20+%20tipValue1;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SpannableString%20finalString%20=%20new%20SpannableString(LeftText+%20%22%5Cn%22%20+%20RightText);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20finalString.setSpan(new%20AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),%20LeftText.length()%20,%20LeftText.length()%20+RightText.length(),%20Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tipFrame1.setText(finalString);) but there is new line sing "\n". I noticed that If I replace " " with "\n" "right" String is on the right side of TextView but little lower (becasue of the new line sing) but I want this whole text to be in the same line. Can I do something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this in a single TextView without splitting it into two, you can try something like this:

```
String leftText = "Left";
String rightText = "Right";
SpannableString finalString = new SpannableString(leftText+ " " + rightText);

Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);

textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        float textViewContentWidth = textView.getWidth() - textView.getPaddingStart() - textView.getCompoundPaddingEnd();
        float leftTextWidth = textView.getPaint().measureText(leftText);
        float rightTextWidth = textView.getPaint().measureText(rightText);

        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(textViewContentWidth - rightTextWidth - leftTextWidth), 1);

        finalString.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), leftText.length(), leftText.length() + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(finalString);
        return true;
    }
});
```

The idea is as follows (assuming that the left and right texts do not overlap):

1. Concatenate strings with a space, as in the original question.
2. Measure the distance between the left and right texts and create a transparent drawable of this width.
3. Use [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan) to replace the space from step 1.

Comment: when I use that rightText string is under leftText one. Also rightText is cut ("ight")

Comment: @KyluAce haven't you modified anything in my solution? I've checked this one, nothing is cut and wrapped

Comment: yea I didn't changed anything. Maybe it's because of some margins/padding of textView?

Comment: @KyluAce did it work for you?

Comment: I will check it tomorrow and I will give you notice.

Comment: there is also something that will work if for example I will add BOLD style to left part of text? Right now when I add that style text goes to another line.

Comment: @KyluAce when do you add it? after `textView.getPaint().measureText(leftText)` has been called?

Comment: when I move up 'SpannableString finalString = new SpannableString(leftText + " " + rightText);
                finalString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, leftText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);' it's still a problem

Comment: @KyluAce measuring spannable text looks a bit trickier than just `paint.measureText(...)`, maybe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613819) helps

Comment: or maybe there is an other way to change stale to part of text?

Comment: ok I figured it out TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(finalTextView.getPaint());
                textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true); works and also I need to add additional space to leftTextWidth

Comment: @KyluAce looks like your variant should measure text correctly

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable solution is to have two `TextView`s aligned in a single horizontal [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/linear) or a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/relative).

Better yet, use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) as the root layout of your screen to avoid nested layouts.

Comment: Yea that will works without a problem and will be easy to implement but first of all it's not optimal solution (nested Layouts). Also even better will be usage of FrameLayout but still i'm looking for something that will works with single TextView

Comment: FrameLayout is designed for stacking views on top of each other so it isn't optimal for this. ConstraintLayout on the other hand will allow you to avoid nested layouts. Edited the answer.